# Tomcat created directory have different owner and group on server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, mkdir

I have a simple JSP page that creates a directory on centOS server root

```
 <% File f= new File("/test/testdir");

if(f.mkdir()){

  %>
```

generated a **.WAR** file and deployed on server. when i run this code. the created directory
***testdir*** have following attributes.
it should have **tomcat** as a owner. **tomcat** is a user on my server and tomcat is the member of **tgroup** group.

i need that the directory should have owner as **tomcat** and group as a **tgroup**
[image]

Comment: Change the file permissions from the linux built-in command:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: this is not requirement. permissions should be same for all files. current and future files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tomcat process is running as root (which is not a good thing). Since you already have a separate `tomcat` user setup, complete the process of always running Tomcat as that user:

Assuming:

1. Install directory is /opt/tomcat (replace with your value)
2. Startup script is /etc/init.d/tomcat (modify to reflect your startup
   script)

```sh
    sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat stop
    sudo chown -R tomcat:tgroup /opt/tomcat
    sudo -u tomcat /etc/init.d/tomcat start
```

You may choose to hard code the user to run as in your startup script, which would be beneficial if you are setting Tomcat up to run on boot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are running tomcat with the user root. Change the user you are using to run tomcat process.

Comment: tomcat process should be running from tomcat user?

Comment: The only reason I know to run tomcat as root is to force it using the port 80. But generally it is suggested to not run tomcat as root, it could be dangerous.

Comment: Yes Asghar. Create a tomcat user and tgroup then assign privileges required to run for tomcat and automatically the directory structure would be created as the tomcat user.